# access random item in list within dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following:

```
topic = {'Countries': ['Somalia', 'Bermuda'],
         'Cars'     : ['Tesla', 'Lotus']
}
```

How do i access a random item from a list, within randomised dictionaries? Did try combining the elements within each list into a list, though that is not exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `random.choice` on the `.keys()`, then again on the value associated with the chosen key:

```
import random

key = random.choice(list(topic.keys()))
value = random.choice(topic[key])
```

We need to turn the result of `.keys()` (a dict view) into a list for you to be able to make a random choice from them.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> topic = {'Countries': ['Somalia', 'Bermuda'],
...          'Cars'     : ['Tesla', 'Lotus']
... }
>>> key = random.choice(list(topic.keys()))
>>> value = random.choice(topic[key])
>>> value
'Tesla'
```

Comment: It sounds logically correct to me, but how does the "list" in your suggestion work? It gives an error without the "list"?

Comment: @brainsfrying: it gives an error, yes: `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`. The dict view acts as an iterator, and `list()` will take all elements from an iterator and add them to a new list instance.

Comment: Your explanation helps as well :)

Comment: @brainsfrying In Python 2 `topic.keys()` returns a list, so no `list` constructor is needed. In Python 3 they made `topic.keys()` to return the same as `topic.viewkeys()`, which doesn't support indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which is uniformly random over all items - if there are 1000 cars and 1 country, it'll pick cars more frequently

```
import random
# build a list of containing key/value pairs
values = [(k, v) for k, values in topic.items() for v in values]

# pick one of these
key, value = random.choice(values)
```